Can liquid hydrogen be oriented along a single axis?
I ran into a fascinating little fact I didn't remember hearing before: if H2 is cooled below 60 K, its heat capacity looks like that of a monoatomic gas.  It simply doesn't have enough thermal energy to rotate, due to quantum effects.
Inevitably I find myself wondering how that works...  in particular, does this mean you could take a container of liquid hydrogen at 14K or so and purify out molecules where the hydrogens are at opposite ends of an arbitrary x, y, or z axis as desired?  (And to make that answer meaningful, how long would they actually stay that way once purified?)

There is no liquid hydrogen at 60 K. This temperature is above the critical point.

Technically I said the liquid H2 cooled below 60K, but OK, I can change that. :)  Also, after some consideration, I think the molecule will rotate at exp(-60/14) of its normal rate, still too fast to separate out, but we'll see what the real answer is from someone in a minute. :)

Wikipedia blows this up. It reports that the low-pressure phase of solid hydtogen has freely rotating molecules.

I was having some probable errors during my first attempt, but I'm calculating something like km/s for the rotational speed of the hydrogen atoms.  If we cool it down to 1/4 of the thermal energy needed to rotate the molecule, it will still be in a rotating state sometimes, just e^(-4) less often.  So I think the answer will be it is moving well beyond a walking pace, which means it flips in some tiny fraction of a second, even though it is almost always not rotating.

There's no way hydrogen would make liquid crystals.

In nmr you can move the magnetisation around from axis to axis but the individual nuclear spins still precess about the magnetic fields, it is not possible to align a quantum object in the way you suggest. Same thing applies to molecular rotational motion. As H2 is light its rotational quantum is v large $\approx 61$ cm$^{-1}$ so at low temperature it will mostly be in $J=0$  so will be oriented at all angles by uncertainty principle in the absence of an external field.

However, hydrogen does have spin isomers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_isomers_of_hydrogen, where there is quantum alignment within each molecule. Being the only common substance* where the nucleus is just a proton, the effect is surprisingly large, causing boil-off of stored hydrogen if not pre-converted. *Well, one can make muon-proton and similar atoms...

Molecules will quickly flip between rotating and not rotating state, whatever ratio between them would be. So any oriented static patterns would be quickly randomised.

I believe the question can be answered on the basis of whether the molecule can couple to an external field, similar to what porphyrin mentioned (in NMR an external magnetic field is used), as in the Zeeman or Stark effects.

An analogy: superfluid helium has no heat stored in translational motion of atoms. Nevertheless, it is not a solid even near absolute zero -- position of atoms can be uncertain even without any motion.
